# Submitting a form with different values using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am new to forms, and Javascript, so please be forgiving.

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="control" name="myform">
<input type="submit" name="Name" value="Do A"/>
<input type="submit" name="Name" value="Do B" />
<input type="submit" name="Name" value="Do C" />
<input type="submit" name="Name" value="Close" />
</form>
```

I need to change this so that there are two buttons, and the form is submitted using javascript dependent on some external conditions, so I want it to look something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="control" name="myform">
<script>
function submitForm(form){
    if(someConditionA){
        submit the form so that the script performs same action as if the button Do A had been clicked
    } if (someConditionB){
        submit the form so that the script performs same action as if the button Do B had been clicked
    } if (someConditionC){
        submit the form so that the script performs same action as if the button Do C had been clicked
    }
}

function closeForm(form){
    window.close();
}
</script>
<button name="doAction" onClick="SubmitForm(this.form)">Do Action<\button>
<button name="close" onClick="SubmitForm(this.form)">Close<\button>
</form>
```

How can I implement the function submitForm?

Thanks

Comment: For starters, you have `SubmitForm` in your event handler, but the function is called `submitForm`. `this.form` doesn't exist. Your submit buttons should have different names to differentiate them.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. The buttons have to have the same name so that the cgi script can process it

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "submit the form so that it performs same action as Do A above"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden field with the same name as the original submit buttons:

```
<input type="HIDDEN" name="Name" value=""/>
```

Set the value of that field based on your conditions:

```
function submitForm(form){
    if(someConditionA){
        form.Name.value = "Do A";
    } if (someConditionB){
        form.Name.value = "Do B";
    } if (someConditionC){
        form.Name.value = "Do C";
    }
    form.submit();
}
```

Change the new Close button to this:

```
<button name="close" onClick="this.form.Name.value='Close';this.form.submit();">Close<\button>
```

I haven't tested this, so it may contain a mistake or two, but that's the general idea. (+1 for 'this.form', not many folks know about that, nice.)

Comment: Same as my answer above, but a lot more detailed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have just figured out the answer to my question:

The way to do it is to have a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Name" value=""/>
```

Then in the function, set this hidden field to have the same value as the respective button.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should simply name your submit buttons differently.

```
<form method="post" action="control" name="myform">
    <input type="submit" name="SubmitA" value="Do A"/>
    <input type="submit" name="SubmitB" value="Do B" />
</form>
```

This way, when submitted, the server will be able to distinguish which submit was clicked.

Comment: In my question I said that only two buttons were needed

Comment: The fields you're saying should be edited don't exist, they've been replaced with the code the OP wants help with. BTW, it wasn't me, just thought I'd help out.

Comment: @MarkFisher: You guys are missing the point. The form should **work** without JavaScript enabled, and then **work *better*** with JavaScript enabled. The form shouldn't work only if JavaScript is enabled, as users without it will lose functionality.

Comment: @Truth: because I wanted two buttons, but the same functionality. With  your solution, I can only Do A and Do B, I can't Do C or Close